# How can I `orderyBy` a pivot table of a pivot table in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-9

I want to be able to order in the following order:

- Group `ends_at`
- Group `name`
- Subgroup `name` (if there's a subgroup)
- Group/User pivot's `role`

Honestly I have no idea where to start. Up to now I what's in the blade file below. Maybe some of that should be in the controller? Using Laravel 9.

**User.php**

```php
public function groups(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Group::class)
            ->using(GroupUserPivot::class)
            ->withPivot(
                'id',
                'role',
                'subgroup_id',
            );
    }
```

**Group.php**

```php
public function subgroups(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Subgroup::class)
            ->orderBy('name');
    }
```

**GroupUserPivot.php**

```php
    public function group(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Group::class);
    }

    public function subgroup(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Subgroup::class);
    }
```

**groups.blade.php**

```php
@foreach ($user->groups()->latest('ends_at')->orderBy('name')->orderByPivot('role')->get() as $userGroup)
    <h1>{{ $userGroup->name }}</h1>
    @if ($userGroup->pivot->subgroup)
        {{ $userGroup->pivot->subgroup->name }}
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: use this library [laravel-sub-query](https://github.com/Alexmg86/laravel-sub-query)

Comment: @SandroJhulianoCagara I looked into the library you shared. I'm not sure which function would be beneficial in this situation.